# Annotations do not always appear in Grafana depending on the time frame

Tags: grafana

I'm working on a dashboard using prometheus and the annotations work fine until my time frame exceeds 3 hours. After that, then we can see that some of the annotations disappear. The one thing I did notice is that the annotations that do appear are the ones where the metric I want to annotate happens more frequently. The ones that are missing are those that only exists for a very short time (<10 seconds).

Is there something that I can do to make this work? The main concern is that I want to be able to see when this occurs overnight and right now, unless I view the data in chunks, I won't be able to see that.

Edit: Forgot to add that this is Grafana v9.3.2.

Comment: It depends on what query you are using right now, and what kind of panel you use.

Comment: If you have trivial query like `my_metric`, you can try something like `last_over_time(my_metric[$__interval]).

Comment: First, this is a Time series panel. Second, I don't want to just see the last time it happens, I want to see every time it happens regardless of interval.

Comment: You cannot see *every* occurrence: if two or more events with same labels happened withing single interval Grafana needs to squash them into one in some way. If you need to see every occurrence - consider other panels more text- or table- based approach.

Comment: Let me see if I can make this clearer: the metrics that go missing are ones that do appear normally. For example, if the metric hits at 3:00 in the morning. If I view that in a 3 hour window, it will show up. Assuming there are no other ones near that time, if I move to a 24 hour window, that annotation at 3:00 will not appear anymore. There's no conflict with other metrics/annotations. It just doesn't show up.

Comment: Yes and to solve this you can use `last_over_time(my_metric [$__interval])` to stretch metrics of short presence to at least on tick of graph's resolution in Grafana's panel. This "stretch", as you yourself pointed, might squash neighboring events into one, but it's inevitable for any solution within use of graph.

Comment: First, apologies. I now see what you're saying. Second, unfortunately, that didn't work. Looking at my data now, I see three groupings when I look at a 1 hour window, each being about 15 minutes apart. If I expand it to three hours, I lose the smallest of those groupings.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you suspect them being squashed, or they simply do not appear? If latter, can you inspect your panel to see if data was passed by Prometheus, and omitted by Grafana, or other way around?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The annotations simply aren't appearing and it's only when the query is run to create annotations. If I run it normally as part of a graph panel or using Explore, the query works fine, so I don't believe it's the query and instead is something with annotations themselves. That being said, it doesn't look like I can debug annotations.